# How can I change the value of a drop down menu with irregular HTML? (Python/Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

Problem:  I want to change drop down menu from "Assigned" value to "Resolved" value.

Normally, I'd just select the element and send_keys the value I want to select, but that won't work in this case.  I have found a workaround which is to select another element that can be selected and 
send_keys(Keys.TAB, "Resolved") to select the drop down menu and change its value.  The problem with this is that it occasionally says the element I've selected isn't visible and crashes.

I'd like to be able to directly select the element and change its value without using the tab method.

Here is the html for the object.

```
  <div class="core_status" name="core.status" id="core.status0">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="3" aria-haspopup="true">
      <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">Assigned</div>
      <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The dropdown menu is currently set to "Assigned", and I want my script to set it to "Resolve".

Here is what I'm using.

```
driver.find_element_by_name("core.summary").click()
driver.find_element_by_name("core.summary").send_keys(Keys.TAB,"R")
```

Comment: Your html doesn't include 'Resolved' anywhere - is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Select class? It should be something like:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
Select(driver.find_element_by_name('core.summary')).select_by_index(1)
```

Unfortunately this depends on the order and amount of items. Worst case you should be able to loop through the Select.get_options list to find what you need and then either select by index or visible text.